# Adding Windows 2016 to WDS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, wds, wim

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL> dism /export-image /sourceimagefile:F:\sources\install.swm /swmfile:F:\sources\install*.swm /sourceindex:1 /destinationimagefile:C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install.wim
```

I can successfully pull the image out so that it is in .wim form, but how do I add all the other source indexes to the same .wim file?

Comment: Hey Frank can I get more specifics? Is this an official windows image? What format are you originating from? (wim,swm,etc...) How are you deploying this? Any special methods for deployment? Is this a WDS question or a WIM question? Thanks!

Comment: swm to wim. WDS does not support swm at least under windows server 2012 r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I managed to do it:

I'm guessing I could have done it off the main image without having to export each individually then importing them.

```
imagex.exe /export C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install1.wim 1 C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install2016.wim "Windows Server 2016 Standard Core" /compress maximum
imagex.exe /export C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install2.wim 1 C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install2016.wim "Windows Server 2016 Standard" /compress maximum
imagex.exe /export C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install3.wim 1 C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install2016.wim "Windows Server 2016 Standard 2" /compress maximum
imagex.exe /export C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install4.wim 1 C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install2016.wim "Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Core" /compress maximum
imagex.exe /export C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install5.wim 1 C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install2016.wim "Windows Server 2016 Datacenter" /compress maximum
imagex.exe /export C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install6.wim 1 C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL\Desktop\install2016.wim "Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 2" /compress maximum
```